# In jQuery how do I create alert every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I do this using jQuery or should I be looking at using something else?

Comment: Short answer: The same as in JavaScript ;) (there is no special jQuery functionality for that).

Comment: No need for jQuery. Plain old `setInterval()` will do

Comment: possible duplicate of [setInterval vs setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `jQuery.delay()` function is designed to delay execution of functions in the jQuery queue.
There is already a built-in Javascript function for handling interval functionality, you wouldn't use jQuery to achieve that.

```
setInterval(function() {
    alert("Message to alert every 5 seconds");
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Again, no need for jQuery here:

```
setInterval(function() { 
   alert("How Now Brown Cow");
}, 5000);
```

(Don't tell anyone, but @Justin Niessner is right, jQuery *is* JavaScript)

Comment: I giggle every time I see people referring to JS as jQuery

Comment: Technically, you can do EVERYTHING in vanilla JavaScript that you would use jQuery for since jQuery IS JavaScript.

Comment: I agree, jQuery is really the best, it solves all kinds of browser problems and is good, as well

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`.  There may be a jQuery specific helper function as well.

`setInterval()` takes 2 parameters - a function to execute, and the delay in milliseconds between calls.  It will keep calling the function until you change or pages or call `clearInterval(intervalID)`.  You have to pass in the value returned by `setInterval()` to clear it.

`setTimeout()` takes the same parameters, but it will only execute once.  You can get around that by having the last line in the function you pass to `setTimeout()` call `setTimeout()` again.

I've noticed that in some browsers, you're restricted in what you can do with `setInterval()` - for instance, it might not let you call `setInterval()` on page load.

Answer (score 0):

I use this script [Cookbook/wait](http://docs.jquery.com/Cookbook/wait) with a small plugin and it works pretty well:

```
(function($){

   $.fn.runItIf = function(ex, fn, args) {

      var self = this;

      return $(self).queue(function() {

          args = args || [];
          if (ex)
             fn.apply.(self, args );

          $(self).dequeue();
      });
   };

   $.fn.runIt = function(fn, args) {

     return $(this).runItIf(true, fn, args);

   };

   $.fn.wait = function(time, type) {

        time = time || 1000;
        type = type || "fx";

        return this.queue(type, function() {
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(self).dequeue();
            }, time);
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Example based on the example in [Cookbook/wait](http://docs.jquery.com/Cookbook/wait):

```
   function runIt() {

      var expression = true;

      $("div").wait()
              .animate({left:'+=200'},2000)
              .runIt(function() { /* ... */ } ).wait(10)
              .runItIf(expression, function() { /* ... */ } ).wait(10)
              .animate({left:'-=200'},1500,runIt);
   }
   runIt();
```