# what's the difference between javascript timeout and timer methods

Tags: javascript

JS support timeout and timer. Here is their definition:

timeout - repeat execution of a code within specific time and it returns an integer that can be used to cancel pending timeout.

```
var timeout_id = setTimeout(f,500);
cleartTimeout(timeout_id);
```

timer - repeat exectuion of code at specific interval.

```
id = setInterval(F,5000);
clearInterval(id)
```

I am a little confused, what is their difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [setInterval vs setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout)

Comment: @cHao I think what Neal meant (and what I also think) is that if no one select the correct answer, people like me lose interest in helping out, cause one of the most beaufitul thing here is that you can atually feel you've helped and that person is greateful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setTimeout executes the code only once.

setInterval executes the code at every xxx amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Interval repeats indefinitely (unless you clear it)

Timout repeats **once** (unless you clear it)

See the difference in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/KS2pF/

Answer (score 1):

setInterval will continue to run repeatedly until you stop it, setTimeout will run once.

Answer (score 0):

Start using MDN Docs:

- [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)
- [setinterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setinterval)