# setTimeout() and canvas not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here's my code. I created a VIBGOYR pattern on the canvas and want to change the radial gradient of the system after a time interval so that it looks animated.

```
function activate(index){
  canvas =document.getElementById("exp");
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  //Start.
  draw(index);

  //Functions.
    function draw(index){
      drawGradiantSq(index);
      var t=setTimeout(doTimer,1000);
  }

  function doTimer(){
      draw(index+10);
  }

  function drawGradiantSq(fi){
      console.log(fi);
      var g1 = context.createRadialGradient(0,300,0,500,300,fi);
      colors = ["violet","indigo","blue","green","orange","yellow","red"];
      var x= 1/12;

      for (var i=0;i<colors.length;i++){
          g1.addColorStop(i*x,colors[i]);
      }
      context.fillStyle = g1;
      context.fillRect(0,0,500,600);

      var g2 = context.createRadialGradient(1000,300,0,500,300,fi);

      for (var i=0;i<colors.length;i++){
          g2.addColorStop(i*x,colors[i]);
      }
      context.fillStyle = g2;
      context.fillRect(500,0,1000,600);
  }
}
```

But the output i'm getting only changes the gradient only once although the timer seems to be working fine.
The HTML file:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="exp" width="1000px" height="600px"></canvas>
    <button onclick="activate(index+=10);">Paint</button>
</body>
```

The variable index is a global variable set to 0.

Comment: index stays unchanged, try `function doTimer(){draw(index+=10);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`.

`setTimeout` is only triggered once:
['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout/#2696711)

Comment: Why the downvote from whoever you are? This is a valid answer.

Comment: Callbacked `doTimer` calls `draw` that calls `setTimeout` again.

Comment: Ah right, apologies. I did not see the recursion.

Interestingly it was marked as the answer, however.