# setInterval and clearInterval, How to run only 1 time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I only want to run the function 1 time.

```
timerA = setInterval(function()
         {
            //codes..
            clearInterval(timerA);
         }, 2000);
```

I want to call the function inside setInterval only 1 time. How can I do it with setInterval and clearInterval?

Or is there another technique to do it?

Comment: use setTimeout instead, also, this is core javascript? why the jquery tag?

Comment: I've asked, if is there an another technique to do it?" Because I am using both frameworks.

Comment: Your approach is fine as well.

Comment: @Asad As well? It's the only approach, isn't it? There is no alternative.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas No, clearly `setTimeout` works too.

Comment: @Asad Ah, you were referring to `setInterval`? I was referring to `setTimeout`. However, `setInterval` is not a good approach. If a function has to be invoked once after a delay, then `setTimeout` is the proper way to do it, but `setInterval` is not.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I know. I'm just saying what he has works.

Comment: @Asad It works but it's not a fine approach. It should be refactored into a `setTimeout`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I have already agreed with this, so I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @Asad Well, your initial comment is still visible. If you don't agree with it anymore, consider deleting it.

Comment: Classic stack0verflow, they ignore your answer and tell you to use something else

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [setTimeout](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-use-jquery-settimeout-function.html) method if you only want it to run once.

**Example:**

```
 setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 5 seconds
 }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to run the code once, I would recommend using `setTimeout` instead:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   //code
}, 2000);
```

---

['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout)

Answer (score 4):

Use `setTimeout` instead:

```
setTimeout(function() { [...] }, timeout);
```

this will execute the function only once after `timeout` milliseconds.