# Parsing setInterval ID's to it's parameter function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, setinterval

I'm going to be executing lot's of setIntervals, there's a way to make it more efficient; but that's down the road.

Is there a way I can do this?

```
var a = setInterval(function(a){
    console.log(a);
    clearInterval(a);
}, 1000, a);
```

So the ID is parsed into the function itself, this way I wont have to store the ID to clear it again.

Comment: Perhaps you could use [setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686867/setinterval-and-clearinterval-how-to-run-only-1-time) instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, would work but I was just looking for a few quick changes to test, I'll end up making more efficient like i said to use only one set interval as a main loop rather than sub loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here.

Recursive setTimeout:

```
function doTheJob() {
  console.log("I'm working")
  setTimeout(doTheJob, 1000)
}
```

Simple setinterval with leaving the variable(id) in scope:

```
var id = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("I'm working")

  if( something ) 
    clearInterval(id)   
}, 1000)
```

Comment: What exactly is the `.bind(this)` for? The lexical scope of a function is not affected by `.bind`.

Comment: Just to be clear, your second solution works exactly the same without `.bind(this)`. `bind` sets the `this` value of the function. Since you are not using `this` inside the function it doesn't matter what the value is set to. Don't confuse `this` with scope.

Comment: Thanks, already figured this out. I bet setTimeout and setInteval changed the scope before =)

Comment: If I do this several times though, the variable will be re-written, thus I'm using an object with the key being each players unique ID, although this isn't the best; I'll be upgrading to using a single loop eventually. Thanks for your suggestion of the tail chasing function!

Answer (score 2):

You could write a helper function that does that:

```
function interval(f, timeout) {
  const id = setInterval(() => f(id), timeout);
}

interval(a => { console.log(a); clearInterval(a); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and using ES6!

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [];
a.push(setInterval(function(t){
    console.log(a[t]);
    clearInterval(a[t]);
}, 1000, a.length));
```

Don't do like that.

Comment: Interesting idea, although a bit messy! Thanks for your suggestion!