# Javascript not updating function every two minutes

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a piece of javascript code which i want to call every two minutes, however i can not seem to get it to work, when the page loads for the first time it works fine, but it doesn't update after that.

Please see code below:

```
 function position(){
 var a=setTimeout(position,60000);
 }


if(navigator.geolocation)
{
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
{
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;
   var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  //not the cross browser way of doing it
   xmlHttp.open("GET", "locator/test1.php?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon, true); 
   xmlHttp.send(null);

   });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: First, `setTimeout` runs once, `setInterval` runs repeatedly. Second, 60000 = 1 minute, not two.

Comment: Aren't you just calling 'position'  recursively?

Comment: by the way 60000 ms = 1 minute, if you want 2 minutes then set 120000

Comment: Did you copy your code out of your project cause all your doing is calling the closed function `position` over and over again...

Comment: you're calling `position` every 60,000 ms but `position` does not do anything other than call itself. you probably meant to have the rest of the code in the function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is running once because it is not in the function, but never again because you are never starting the timeout. I think you want to restructure like this:

```
function position() {
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lon = position.coords.longitude;
      var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  //not the cross browser way of doing it
      xmlHttp.open("GET", "locator/test1.php?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon, true); 
      xmlHttp.send(null);    
    });
  }

  // fire again in 120000ms (2 minutes)
  setTimeout(position, 120000);
}

// fire the initial call
position()  ;
```

Comment: `// fire again in 120000 **MILLI**secs`, otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  position();
}, 12e5);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, the geolocation functionality isn't actually part of the position function

and position is never called

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout will only run the function once after the specified time is passed. If you want to repeat the function, use setInterval.

See ['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout) for detail

Answer (score 0):

```
function position(){

  if(navigator.geolocation)
  {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
  {
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var lon = position.coords.longitude;
   var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  //not the cross browser way of doing it
   xmlHttp.open("GET", "locator/test1.php?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon, true); 
   xmlHttp.send(null);
}

var a=setInterval(position,120000);
```

Comment: that will not work unless you call position outside the function too

Answer (score 0):

you can try setInterval to do it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

but if you prefer to use setTimeout you need to call your function recursively.

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
 function doSomethingWithPosition(){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  //not the cross browser way of doing it
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "locator/test1.php?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon, true); 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
  });
  //RECURSIVE CALL
  setTimeout(doSomethingWithPosition, 60000);
 }

 //FIRST CALL
 doSomethingWithPosition();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have a suggestion.

I think you want to do this - I use jQuery because of the better Ajax callback functionality

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
  getLoc();
}
function getLoc() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    $.get("locator/test1.php?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon, 
      function(data){ 
        // do something with data returned
        setTimeout(getLoc,120000); // call again in 2 minutes
      }
    ); 
  });
}
```

which will call locator every 2 minutes assuming it successfully calls it the first time