# php javascript cleartimeout() not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a setTimeout and clearTimeout where the setTimeout is working fine but clearTimeout is not working, can anyone help me?

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 0;
  var status = setTimeout(function () {
    if (i <= 2) {
      metrics_status();
      i++;
    } else {
      clearTimeout(status);
    };
  }, 3000);
</script>
<div id="ReloadMetrics"></div>
```

Comment: you cant clear the timeout inside of the timeout... by then it's already over.

Comment: Based on your code I think you meant to use [setInterval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `clearTimeout` outside `setTimeout` like this

```
var status;
if(status){ 
   clearTimeout(status);
}
status = setTimeout(function () { }
```

[Example1](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)
[Example2](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Comment: with out intializing status can we call clearTimeout(status) ?

Comment: @Toms Passing an invalid ID to clearTimeout does not have any effect (and doesn't throw an exception). [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout)

Comment: Thats what i am doing here , is still i am missing anything?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 0;
  var status;
  status = setTimeout(Fun(), 2000);
  function Fun() {
    if (i <= 2) {
      metrics_status();
      i++;
      status = setTimeout(Fun(), 2000);

    } else {
      clearTimeout(status);
    };
  }
</script>
<div id="ReloadMetrics"></div>

Comment: @user1642408, Read all the comments, you're using the `clearTimout` inside `setTimeout` and you must use it outside of it

Comment: thanks, is still i am missing anything?     <script type="text/javascript">
var i = 0;
var status;
if (i >= 2) {
clearTimeout(status);
}
status = setTimeout(function() {metrics_update();i++;}, 2000);
</script>
<div id="ReloadMetrics"></div>

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need `setInterval` instead. which will call your function in specified intervals, until you call the `clearInterval`

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` function called only once if it is recursive then you need to call `clearTimeout`
To call a function multiple times then you use `setInterval` then you can call `clearTimeout`

Example of `setTimeout and clearTimeout` is  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Timing functions http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do your purpose. please check

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = 0;
  var status;
  status = setTimeout(Fun, 3000);
  function Fun() {
    if (i <= 2) {
      metrics_status();
      i++;
      status = setTimeout(Fun, 3000);

    } else {
      //clearTimeout(status);
    };
  }
</script>
<div id="ReloadMetrics"></div>
```

Comment: @Kevin B Thanks. Code modified

Answer (score 0):

take a look on the given example http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/qTGPT/

```
<div id="status"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var i = 0;
var status = setInterval(function() {
    if (i <= 5) {
        //metrics_status();
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = i;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "done";
      _clearTime();
    }
    i++;
  }, 1000);

function _clearTime(){
    return clearInterval(status);
}
```

hope this should work according to your need..