# setinterval with click event is not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, setinterval

I'm having a problem in letting 'setinterval' function to work in 'click' event. it doesn't work at all inside the click event, while if i put it out side the click event it works.. how can i get around this ??

I googled it for a solution, but it seems there is already an issue with it with the 'click' event.. & i hope you can help me guys with it..

thanks.

```
function myTimer() {
    alert("test");
};


$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#testButton').click(function() {
        var myVar = setInterval(function() {
            myTimer();
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**Sorry Guys... it seems that I was having an error on my side.. I put the input button to be runat server & this is was the problem... thank u guys for ur help..
and sorry for this problem ...**

Comment: Are you sure that element with id `testButton` exists?

Comment: a real example would help a lot :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure is working: http://jsfiddle.net/hhUkC/

Comment: @VisioN yah. i'm really sure about the id, i have tested it with the alert ...

Comment: @Q8Y Could you then provide a fiddle or just include your markup in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to use setInterval? setInterval will run the same function all the time, until it is cleared.

Instead of defining a function inside the setInterval call, try just referencing myTimer, ie:

```
$('#testButton').click(function() {
    var myVar=setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
});
```

See ['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout)

Answer (score 1):

Post your html code and check if jquery is included.
You can also check if there're any errors in chrome console or firefox firebug.
Your code works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H2Hjz/) if there's a button on a page

```
<button id="testButton">clickme</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var myTimer = function() {
    alert("test");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testButton').click(function() {
        var reload = function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                myTimer();
                reload();
            }, 1000);
        }
        reload();
    });
});
```