# javascript - setTimeout() vs setInterval()

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, setinterval

What are the minor and major differences between `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`?

I searched the internet but it made me confused! What's the difference between those?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main diffrence is

```
setInterval fires again and again in intervals, while setTimeout only fires once.
```

you can get more differnces in simple words in

[setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout)

Answer (score 2):

tha major difference is that `setTimeout` will execute some code just once, after a given delay, while `setInterval` will execute a code always, with a delay between each call

e.g. try these on your console:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Wait 3 seconds and I appear just once');
}, 3000);
```

and

```
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('Every 3 seconds I appear on your console');
}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Javascript timers MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Timers)

> **setTimeout**()
>
> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after specified delay.
>
> **setInterval**()
>
> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.