# Is it possible to make the setTimeout function behave like setInterval in the continuation?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have two example code.
The two are same purpose, to increase the variable `count` by 1, and print the value.
But the first example using `setInterval`, and the second example using `setTimeout`.

```
var count = 0;

// First example.
var time = setInterval(function() {
   document.body.innerHTML = count;
   count++;
}, 1000);

// Second example.         
var time = setTimeout(function() {
   document.body.innerHTML = count;
   count++;
}, 1000);
```

Why in the first example increases the value of variable and prints its value Continuously, but in the second example increases the value of variable by 1 and prints its value once Then stops and does not continue?

**I ask this question, because I've seen some examples work continuously using `setTimeout` also.**

Comment: Because that's the difference between `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

Comment: Why somebody voted down my question, what's wrong that I done?

Comment: I didn't vote, but you've not given any reason why these functions fail to meet your expectation. Why would they not behave the way they do? Why would you expect them to behave the same? What would be the point of having two functions providing identical functionality? There seems to be a lack of basic research, and perhaps basic reasoning.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout). Being a beginner doesn't excuse one from the task of research.

Comment: Please everybody you don't dealing with anybody ask a question as a professional

Comment: You don't need to be a professional to use Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want setTimeout to "behave" like setInterval you should do something like this

```
var time = function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = count;
    count++;
    setTimeout(time, 1000);
}

time();
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean, because I've seen some examples work continuously using `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thank you, but can you please tell me how this code work step by step (`The implementation priority`) ?

Comment: First, a function called time is declared. The function write the variable 'count' in the body, and then the function calls to itself every 1000 ms

Answer (score 3):

The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds. SetTimeout **will be called only once.**

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
The setInterval() method will continue calling the function **until clearInterval()** is called, or the window is closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not mean that.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously?

Because [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) and [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) *are not the same function...*

The behaviour you have observed is what has been specified for each function.