# how to wait one second in my for loop javascript?

Tags: javascript

Ok I have a random dice number generator. and it will have a for loop and inside the loop I am trouble having to figure out how to wait one second like this below.

Loading.
wait one sec
Loading..
wait one sec
...

I can do the rest I just need some help with this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Answer (score 3):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval):

```
window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
```

or [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp):

```
setTimeout(function() {  }, 1000);
```

['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout):

`setTimeout(expression, timeout);` runs the code/function once after the timeout.

`setInterval(expression, timeout);` runs the code/function in intervals, with the length of the timeout between them.

Comment: Passing of parameters is not supported by a good number of browsers in use.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Will call the function at a particular interval

Answer (score 0):

In function foo, you can define all stuff that you need to be executed.

```
var foo = function{
}

var timeout = setInterval(foo, 1000);
```

and when you want to stop execution

```
clearInterval(timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use setTimeout or setInterval :

```
timer = setTimeout(function(){/*your code here */}, 1000);
```

or

```
timer = setInterval(function(){/*your code here */},1000);
```

and once you would like to clear the timer use :

`clearTimeout(timer);`

or

`clearInterval(timer);`