# setTimeout vs setInterval - best practices on use

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I understand the differences between setTimeout and setInterval, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout) explained it quite nicely.

This question is about best practice when using timers, specifically setTimeout vs setInterval.

If I need to call a countdown several times in a game fairly frequently (for example, a player moves to a new location, which triggers a new countdown which will encourage them to move in **5 seconds**), but it's not necessarily uniform intervals (meaning, they should move to next location, but can hang out at current location and be penalized), is it better performance-wise, and clean code-wise to:

a) keep clearing and setting `setTimeout()` when the player decides to change location

```
if (player.newLocation !== player.oldLocation) { //player location has changed
        window.clearTimeout(myTimer);
        myTimer = setTimeout(function() { 
            do something
        },50);  
}
```

b) keep setInterval running, but change a variable that acts as that countdown each time the player moves to a new location

```
var counter = 0;
if (player.newLocation !== player.oldLocation) {
    counter = 100;
}

myTimer = setInterval(function() { 
    if (counter > 0) {
          // do something...
          counter--;
    }
},50);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*consistently call*" but "*not necessarily uniform intervals*"?

Comment: @Bergi worded that wrong. I mean I will be needing a countdown many times... as each time the player moves to a new specified location (like, jumps to a new square on a board, it will begin a new countdown, or reset the countdown)

Comment: OK, I see. But these countdowns are not running concurrently, do they?

Comment: @Bergi No they don't need to and shouldn't.

Comment: for the use you describe, performance is not even a tiny factor. if you had an idle mode, setTimeout allows you to temporarily increase the delay without re-subscribing, but perf is about the same all around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it better performance-wise

Not keeping timers around when they are not needed is definitely better. Regardless whether they're implented with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

> and clean code-wise

That depends on how (often) "*the player decides to change location*", and how this is signaled to your code. It might make an actual difference in behaviour, and you should aim to keep your code *correct* - independent from the sequence and timing of inputs. Keep it simple, and choose what you need.

Comment: The player will need to make a decision to move within 5 seconds... but they don't necessarily need to move (ie, if they don't move, they will lose points) - which is where the "not necessarily uniform intervals)

Comment: Sounds like you want individually triggered (started & stopped) intervals then.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably fine to do either one unless you are concerned about performance. ie you are doing something processor intensive when the countdown is complete. In that case I would say it depends on how often players move. If they are twitchy (move a lot) then go ahead and use setInterval. If they only move occasionally then the setTimeout would probably be better.