# Fade In & Out Interval Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css-transitions, fadein, fadeout

How can I have this fiddle to change from first content (mario) to next content (smiley face) without being on hover/click? I want it to change automatically after 5 seconds. Also from second content to third content and fourth content.

Here is a sample from [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/frww/z12gmqwf/). I figured that maybe the coding should be change somewhere here:

```
$('#text1').hover(function () {
    hey();
});
```

Besides that, anyone knows why my fourth content isn't showing?

I am new in this. Please guide me. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I Think you have to use setInterval() see i given one link in my answer why to use setInterval()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` function

```
setTimeout(function () {
     hey();
},5000);
```

Fiddle [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z12gmqwf/6/)

**EDIT**

As per your need shoe after 35 seconds

```
$('#text1,#text2, #text3, #text4').hide();

setTimeout(function () {
   $('#text1').show();
     hey();
},35000);

function hey() {
    setTimeout(function () {
    $("#text1").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });
    });
    },5000);
}
```

Updated fiddle. [NEW FIDDLE UPDATED AS PER COMMENT](http://jsfiddle.net/z12gmqwf/6/)

Comment: hey, do you know how can I have this whole thing to appear (fade in) after 35 seconds? thanks.

Comment: oh sorry, i meant starting from mario (the first image). :/

Comment: change the time 5000 to 35000 in the very first code . mario image will be shown for 35 seconds..den changes the next pic.

Comment: i know. i did that. but i want mario to appear after 35seconds. not mario appearing for 35 seconds.

Comment: lol. yes i tried the second fiddle. all i want is for this whole thing to appear AFTER 35 seconds. that means when u first open this fiddle, the fiddle is blank for/until 35 seconds, then mario comes up with following content. sorry, i made you confuse :(

Comment: Check now.... may this wat u need...Now mario will appear after 35 seconds..and changes to next image after 35 sec.

Comment: yes! that's exactly what i want! you are amazing! thank you thank you so muchh :D

Comment: oh yeah, why isn't the fourth content showing up tho? :/

Answer (score 1):

Just add `setTimeout(hey, 5000);` instead hover handler:

```
$('#text2, #text3, #text4').hide();
setTimeout(hey, 5000);

function hey() {
    $("#text1").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: hey, do you know how can I have this whole thing to appear (fade in) after 35 seconds? thanks.

Comment: Hide all `text#`, set time to 35000 in `setTimeout` and add `fadeIn` for `#text1` in function.

Comment: this is what i came up with: 

$('#text2, #text3, #text4').hide();
$('#text').hide();


setTimeout(function () {
     hey();
},35000);

function hey() {
    setTimeout(function () {
    $("#text1").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
            });
        });
    });
    },5000);
}

Comment: It's because you didn't show it. You need to add `fadeOut` for third element and `fadeIn` for fourth. http://jsfiddle.net/z12gmqwf/8/

Answer (score 1):

Your **hey()** is showing upto 3rd text.Add another next() transition.

```
function hey() {
    $("#text1").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).next().fadeIn("slow",function(){
                    $(this).delay(2500).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: hey, do you know how can I have this whole thing to appear (fade in) after 35 seconds starting from mario (the first image)? thanks.

Comment: use setTimeout function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change content automatically after 5 second you should use setTimeout function, for example:

`setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 5000)` this will triger alert box after 5 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

I Think you have to use [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
setInterval(function(){   hey(); }, 3000);
```

[See this Link what is difference between **setTimeout** and
 **setInterval**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696711/4696809)