# Slider only displays first content element

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<button onclick="slider1.swapImage()">Function</button>

<p id="slide" width="400"></p>

<script language="JavaScript"> 

  var slider =function(){}

  slider.prototype.swapImage=function() 
  { 
    var path = new Array(); 
    var i = 0; 

    // Array of Content

    path[0] = "hello"; 
    path[1] = "hello1"; 
    path[2] = "hello2";

    document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML = path[i]; 

    if(i < path.length - 1) i++; 
    else i = 0; 

    setTimeout("swapImage()",2500); 
  };

  var slider1 = new slider;

</script>
```

"swapImage is not a function" 
Is the error i am facing  and this is happening after the it has displayed the first element of the array.How to make the content slider display all the contents one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path and index properties should be defined on the slider class itself. Currently you initialize the list everytime the function is called!

The setTimeout Method also expects a function as argument.
In your case the setInterval Method fits better. ['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout)

Why do you have the "swapImage is not a function" Error? That's because you reference to a global function called "swapImage", but you defined the method on the slider class so you have to use the this keyword. 
I think you are missing some basics about object oriented programming. That's a good starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

I refactored the code: https://jsfiddle.net/9hh9v28x/12/

HTML

```
<button onclick="start()">start</button>
<p id="slide" width="400"></p>
```

Javascript

```
// Class Definition
var Slider = function() {
        // Array of Content
        this.path = ["hello1", "hello2", "hello3"];
    this.currentIndex = 0;
};

Slider.prototype.nextSlide = function() {
  // set text
  document.getElementById("slide").innerHTML = this.path[this.currentIndex]; 

  // count up index and set it back to 0 when the end of the "path" array is reached
  this.currentIndex++;
  if(this.currentIndex >= this.path.length){
    this.currentIndex = 0;
  }
};

// 
function start() {
    var slider1 = new Slider();

  // call method on start
  // otherwise you have to wait 2.5 secs to see something (wenn the setInterval() triggers)
    slider1.nextSlide();

  // The set interval method calls the given function
  // every given seconds (in this case 2.5)
  window.setInterval(function(){
    slider1.nextSlide();
  }, 2500);
}
```