# How to make the refresh frequency of setTimeout a variable?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want a function I am writing to call itself automatically.   I want to be able to parse the frequency at which it calls itself via the first time I parse it.  It would then use that same value internally with the JS setTimeout() function to call itself repeatedly again at the same frequency.

So you can see what I have in the sample below:

```
function testFunction(refreshFrequ){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("frequency: "+refreshFrequ);
        testFunction(refreshFrequ);
    }, refreshFrequ);
}

// run the 1st time
testFunction(5000);
```

The problem is that this doesn't work as from the second time it runs onwards the parsed timeout isn't evaluated.   The console output gives a clue to what's going on here:

> frequency: undefined

How would I get this working, nothing so far has helped.

Comment: I just ran this on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rfq4af0/) on Chrome and it seems to be working just fine. I see `frequency: 5000` every 5 seconds. What environment is this not working for you? I've also added another call `testFunction(2000)` and it seems to be writing to console separately and at the proper times.

Comment: Odd... I'm also running current Chrome on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Window setInterval() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696711/3900089) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/729943/3900089) for more information.

```js
var autoInterval;
var elapsed = 0;

function myStartFunction(refreshFrequ) {
  if (!autoInterval) {
    autoInterval = setInterval(function() {
      elapsed++;
      document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = refreshFrequ * elapsed + " elapsed.";
      console.log("frequency interval: " + refreshFrequ + " x " + elapsed);
    }, refreshFrequ);
  }
}

function myStopFunction() {
  if (autoInterval) {
    clearInterval(autoInterval);
    autoInterval = null;
    elapsed = 0;
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Interval was reset.";
    console.log("interval stopped");
  }
}

myStartFunction(5000);
```

```html
<p>The setInterval() method has started automatically.</p>

<button onclick="myStartFunction(1000)" title="Start with 1000 ms interval. Clicking this button while the event is active should not create a new interval instance.">Start</button> <button onclick="myStopFunction()" title="Click to stop and clear the interval instance.">Stop</button>

<p id="txt">0 elapsed.</p>
```

**Edit**: Although there was no mention of the potential duplicate function calls, [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726811/1839335) should be taken into consideration, especially if the event can arbitrarily be executed. The `if` statement was imposed in order to prevent duplicate events from being stacked up against the original instance; otherwise, each additionally executed function would result in a unique instance, which could then further create unstoppable multiple events, so I must give credit where credit is due. Kudos to [Tymek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729641/tymek)!

Comment: Thank you Brie yes switching to setInterval() has resolved this!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `setInterval` instead.

```
var testFunction = (function () { // This will "build"/"enclose" our function
    var handle = null; // ID of the interval
    return function (freq) {
      if (handle !== null) clearInterval(handle);
      handle = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("frequency: " + freq);
      }, freq);
    };
})();
```

With this if you re-initialize interval, you will not create another instance of it (having 2 functions ticking).

You can learn more about `setInterval` at: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
and more about how JavaScript functions works at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures