# My javascript slidshow code is not working

Tags: javascript

I have no clue why.
I have checkt everything but it should work.
This shuld be a slidshow for a webseit

```
<script src="JS/javascript.js">
    "use strict";
    var image = ['"bilder/1.png"','"bilder/2.png"'];
    var i = 0;

    aengereHintergrund();

    function aengereHintergrund() {
      document.getElementById('hintergund').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+image[i]+')';
      if(i < image.length){
      i ++

      }
      else {
        i = 0
      }
     setTimeout(aengereHintergrund(),3000);
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: Open your console and check the error. What is `src="JS/javascript.js"`?

Comment: Don't put content in a `<script>` tag that also has a `src`.

Comment: What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: i have trid:`<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: If your script tag has a `src` attribute specified, the embedded script is *ignored*.

Comment: Looks like you are messing in the usage of setTimout and setTimeInterval also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, the classic *function reference vs invocation* problem.

Here's what you wrote:

`setTimeout(aengereHintergrund(),3000);`

And here's what you should have written:

`setTimeout(aengereHintergrund,3000);`

In the second case, we're passing the function `aengereHintergrund` itself to `setTimeout`, which is what we want. In the first case, you're *invoking* `aengereHintergrund`, and passing its *result* (which is nothing, aka `undefined`) to `setTimeout`.

(Note: You should also probably use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, so you don't have to invoke it again and again. Also also, instead of branching on `i >= image.length` you can just use `i = (i + 1) % image.length`).

Answer (score 0):

If you write `if (i < images.length) i++;`, `i` will reach `images.length`. You can fix this error with `i++; if (i >= images.length) i = 0;`, or `i = (i + 1) % images.length;` :

```js
var slides = document.getElementById("slides");
var images = ["v67W6.jpg", "USehe.jpg"];
var path = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/";
var i = 0;

nextSlide();

function nextSlide () {
  var bg = "url(" + path + images[i] + ")";
  slides.style.backgroundImage = bg;
  i = (i + 1) % images.length;
  setTimeout(nextSlide, 1000);
};
```

```html
<img id="slides" width="300" height="100" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">
```