# Can't iterate whole alphabet using setInterval

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, setinterval

I want code to iterate each letter every second, but it iterates the whole alphabet in one second.

```js
let alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

setInterval(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    console.log(alphabet[i]);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You are iterating over your array inside setInterval(). I think you want to be doing this outside of setTimeout

Comment: yeah for sure, look what you are doing... "after a second, run this function (that iterates over the whole array)"

Comment: To be clear: the issue here is that you're starting these intervals all at the same time. If you wrap the interval command in a `setTimeout` using `i * 1000` as delay, you should get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you iterate throught entire array, for avoid that, you need add to the index +1 for iterate.

```js
let alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

let i = 0;
let intervalID = setInterval(function (){
    
    console.log(alphabet[i]);
    
    i++;
    
    i < alphabet.length ? null : clearInterval(intervalID);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Increase `i` using `i = (i + 1) % alphabet.length` and this is the best solution.

Comment: You need to clear the setInterval once i is smaller than the array.length, otherwise, it is still running under the background.

Comment: That was the intention, but i change it, thanks for advice!

Comment: Thank you, but how can it run under the background?

Answer (score 2):

No need ah loop simple interval is enough. If iteration reached end of the array use `clearInterval` for stop the itreation

```js
const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']


function run() {
  let i = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (i === alphabet.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return
    }
    console.log(alphabet[i])
    i++
  }, 1000)
}

run()
```

Comment: After a minute it is still logs `undefined`))

Comment: It needs to be `i = (i + 1) % alphabet.length`

Comment: @Leonid now its ready please check updated answer

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks . But i have fixed with `clearInterval`

Comment: thank you, but why did you add `return` after clearInterval?

Comment: Because `index` start from `0`. while end reach on `i=25`  it will display last index value of array . so `i == arr.length` is match `26` index value  is not there on array. so we used `return` to break the execution

Comment: but doesn't `clearInterval` break execution by itself after `if` statement matches?

Comment: yes `clearInterval` stop the `interval` function that mean stop the iteration

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get element one after another after one second then you can use setTimeout instead of setInterval

[setTimeout vs setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout)

```js
let alphabet = [
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d",
  "e",
  "f",
  "g",
  "h",
  "i",
  "j",
  "k",
  "l",
  "m",
  "n",
  "o",
  "p",
  "q",
  "r",
  "s",
  "t",
  "u",
  "v",
  "w",
  "x",
  "y",
  "z",
];

for (let i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(alphabet[i]);
  }, i * 1000);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't loop; I'm pretty sure OP needs it to loop.

Comment: You actually create 27 timeOut function at once in the background. I don't think this is a good solution. They all are running at the same time.

Comment: @ikhvjs First of all there will be `26` timeout and secondly setTimeout just make `26` function in the background ready to call as soon as the main thread is `free`. AFter the functions are called, There job is done. What is it that you think it is not a good solution.

Comment: setTimeout is running in the background and once it is finished, it will be set to the event loop queue. The problem is if there 1000 items in the array, you actually create 1000 setTimeout running in the background at the same time.

Comment: Since there are only `26` values in the array, that's why I came up with this solution. If there were more values then I would've come up with another solution...'

Comment: I can understand. I just think it is unnecessary to use setTimeout for a setInterval job.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include the for loop in your `setInterval`. Instead, you just need to declare an `index` and update it in the setInterval and once the index is out of range of the array, you need to clear the `timer`.

```js
let alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] 
let index= 0;
const timer = setInterval(function () {
  index< alphabet.length
    ? console.log(alphabet[index++])
    : clearInterval(timer);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This doesn't loop. OP needs it to loop.

Comment: @ChrisG,  ```I want code to iterate each letter every second```, is that what OP wants? What do you mean OP need it to loop?

Comment: OP is using setInterval, so I'm pretty sure they want to get `a` again after the first `z`.

Comment: @ChrisG, I see. But somehow he use for loop instead of a indefinite while loop. That’s why I guess they want loop only one time.

Comment: They are starting 26 intervals. So without any further information, they want an interval for each letter.

Comment: @ChrisG, It is fine. The accepted answer is the same as my solution.

Comment: Yeah, but the answerer changed it so it no longer loops... :P Jesus, this page is a trainwreck.

Comment: @ChrisG, And somehow it is what OP wants.....interesting

Answer (score 0):

Only setInterval will be enough here. No need to add a loop.

```
let alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
let counter = 0;
let interval = setInterval( () => {
    console.log( alphabet[ counter++ ] );
    if( counter === alphabet.length ){
        clearInterval( interval );
    }
}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ? clear interval from closure.

```
const alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] 

let i = 0

const timerId = setInterval(function (){
    if(i === alphabet.length){
        clearInterval(timerId);
        console.log('Clear interval')
    }else{
        console.log(alphabet[i++]);
    }
}, 1000);
```