# Javascript automatic click button but JUST one time

Tags: javascript, html

It's my code. This click goes on indefinitely. I would like to stop him after the first time.

```
<input type="button" name="submitbre" id="loadBtn" value="Load More">

<script>
var btn = document.querySelector("[name='submitbre']");
setInterval(function(){
btn.click();
},4000);
</script>
```

Comment: ['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2696692)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. `setTimeout` will run the function just once, while `setInterval` runs the function periodically.

More info: [https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#:~:text=setTimeout%20allows%20us%20to%20run,repeating%20continuously%20at%20that%20interval](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#:%7E:text=setTimeout%20allows%20us%20to%20run,repeating%20continuously%20at%20that%20interval).